# Stuck code during saving an image wiht plotly express

Tags: python, express, plotly

I have an issue when trying to save image as png with plotly express.

I dunno why but the code stuck there.

```
fig = px.line(BV01_VOC_t, x=dates, y=y_data, template="simple_white", labels={"index": "Tempo Trascorso [h]","value": "VOC [ppm]"},markers=True)
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = dates,
        ticktext = ["00:00","00:05","00:10","00:25","00:30","1:00","2:00",'4:00','8:00','24:00','48:00','72:00','96:00']
    )
)

if BV01_VOC_t.max().max() > 1:
    max_yaxis=math.ceil(BV01_VOC_t.max().max())+(math.ceil(BV01_VOC_t.max().max()*0.5))
else:
    max_yaxis=math.ceil(BV01_VOC_t.max().max())
    
fig.update_layout(title_text='BV01 - Test di Biodegradazione: andamento concentrazione di VOC',title_x=0.5)
fig.update_layout(yaxis_range=[0,max_yaxis]) 
fig.update_layout(xaxis_range=[0,4000])
fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=True,tickangle=90)
fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=True)
fig.write_image("test.png")
fig.show()
```

Any idea about why?

Thanks

I am not sure what I can change here, or why I get this issue.

Comment: What is wrong with your code, try to explain your problem?

Comment: Dont save anytime and stuck and command line 'fig.write_image("test.png")'

Comment: Can you try to put multiple print() statements to figure out where it is stuck

Answer (score 1):

Check ur kaleido version if it is other than 0.1.1.post1 pip unistall kaleido.Then install with following version (pip install kaleido==0.1.1.post1)